# Optimization for search

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project and I have some problem with optimization in MySQL. 
My main table looks like and have around 1M rows:

```
+----+------+---------+ 
| id | Name | city_id |  City_id is between (0, 2000).
+----+------+---------+
```

I'll make many queries like:

1. SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id=x
2. SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id=x AND id=rand()

It is only to show you main operations on this database

If i'll make 2k small tables will it  be good solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 2000 tables is almost never a good solution. Why do you suggest this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to draw lots two person who are from the same city, but this query will be use many times per minute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is an index.  Try this:

```
create index idx_table_city_id on table(city_id, id);
```

SQL is designed to handle large tables.  There are very few reasons why you would want to split up data from one table to multiple tables.  The only good reason I can think of are when doing so is needed to meet security requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is what I'm looking for :)
Second question. If I make FOREIGN KEY for city_id MYSQL will be make index automatically?

Comment: @user3740335 . . . No.  Foreign keys don't create indexes.  In a create table statement, `primary key`, `key`, `index`, and `unique` do.